# Setting only global level seed gives same output in consecutive iterations of loop in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am testing out the `tf.random.set_seed` according to the rules given at - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_seed

In particular I am testing the second rule - where we set only global level seed and no operation level seed.

According to the documentation (the link is mentioned above), the second rule is:

> If the global seed is set, but the operation seed is not: The system deterministically picks an operation seed in conjunction with the global seed so that it gets a unique random sequence.

To explain the second rule, the documentation uses the following snippet:

```
tf.random.set_seed(1234)
print(tf.random.uniform([1]))  # generates 'A1'
print(tf.random.uniform([1]))  # generates 'A2'
```

and states that

> The reason we get 'A2' instead 'A1' on the second call of tf.random.uniform above is because the second call uses a different operation seed.

Now, I tested this rule on a 1D tensor of shape (3,) to check if the output of shuffling the tensor does not give the same sequence within consecutive iterations of the loop as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf


"""
Only global level seed
"""

tf.random.set_seed(1234)
   
constant_tensor = tf.constant([1,2,3])

for i in range(1, 15):
    shuffled_tensor = tf.random.shuffle(constant_tensor)
    print(shuffled_tensor)
```

I got the following output:

```
tf.Tensor([3 1 2], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([2 3 1], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([2 1 3], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([2 3 1], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([1 3 2], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([3 2 1], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([2 1 3], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([2 1 3], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([2 3 1], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([2 1 3], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([3 2 1], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([1 2 3], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([3 2 1], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([3 2 1], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
```

From the output you can see that the sequence on line number 7 and 8 match.
Also the sequence on line number 13 and 14 match.

According to the documentation, tensorflow should not output the same sequence in a consecutive iteration.

Then why am I getting this kind of output? Have I misunderstood the concept?

To test this further, I also tested to following snippet which I used to generate 14 1-D tensors and check if any tensor is repeated within consecutive runs as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed(1234)
for i in range(1, 15):
    print(tf.random.uniform(shape=[1], minval=1, maxval=15, dtype=tf.int32))
```

And I got the following output:

```
tf.Tensor([12], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([8], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([1], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([2], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([4], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([3], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([2], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([7], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([13], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([11], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([8], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([3], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([1], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([4], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
```

You can see that no two consecutive tensors are repeated. Why didn't I see this behaviour for my first snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Two different `operation seed` can generate the same sequence. I don't think there is any guarantee that no two consecutive tensors are repeated. For example,

```
tf.random.set_seed(1234)
print(tf.random.shuffle(constant_tensor, seed=6))
print(tf.random.shuffle(constant_tensor, seed=7))

#ouputs are same even though the `operation seed` is different.
tf.Tensor([1 3 2], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([1 3 2], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
```

In your second example if you reduce the `maxval`, you should observe the repetition happening as well.

Comment: Hello Sir! Thank for your answer. So are you trying to say that - tensorflow tries but there is no guarantee.

Also, does this logic applies to all the 4 rules mentioned in the doc?

Comment: You are right. The rules mentions the combinations of the seeds,  it can't guarantee different output. if your `constant array` is large, then the probability of repeating is low.